# After upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 16.7.1 the program hangs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I use Visual Studio Community 2019 with C++ (no .Net). Yesterday I updated to version 16.7.1. Ever since then, Visual Studio hangs on exit at the step "Unloading Projects". No projects are unloaded, and the progress bar never starts moving. The program simply hangs and is unresponsive. The only way out is to kill the process.

It also hangs whenever I try to change the Configuration target for the solution. Both issues occur on any of my solutions that I open. I have tried using Visual Studio Installer to repair the install, but it makes no difference. The installer does report one issue: `Couldn't repair Microsoft.AspNetCore.TargetingPack.3.1.3.1.3` But this hardly seems like it matters to my Win32 projects.

This problem definitely started as soon as I updated to 16.7.1. I don't recall the previous version I had, but I had just updated a few days before so it was probably 16.7. I am posting to see if others have this problem and if anyone has found a solution (other than falling back a version). I will limp along with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. Just use visual studio 2017. Only thing that fixed it for me.